# SQL using NOT EXISTS

Tags: sql, not-exists

I am trying to write an SQL query that returns all student email addresses for clients who have had a new invoice since April 1 and have not yet scheduled a delivery for this fall.  This is returning an empty set even though I know there are entries that meet these conditions.  I've tried a few different things with no luck, is there a way to do this?

```
SELECT clients.studentEmail 
FROM `clients`, `invoices` 
WHERE clients.clientId = invoices.clientId 
AND invoices.datePosted > "2013-04-01" 
AND NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT * 
    FROM appointments, clients
    WHERE clients.clientId = appointments.clientId 
    AND appointments.serviceDirection = "Delivery" 
    AND appointments.date > '2013-07-01')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to relate your `not exists` subquery to the outer query.  For example:

```
select  clients.studentemail 
from    clients c
join    invoices i
on      c.clientid = i.clientid 
where   invoices.dateposted > "2013-04-01" 
        and not exists 
        (
        select  * 
        from    appointments a
        where   c.clientid = a.clientid -- Relates outer to inner query
                and a.servicedirection = "delivery" 
                and a.date > '2013-07-01')
        )
```

Comment: That means he just need to remove the `client` table from sub query?

Comment: Ah, this did seem to work.  I am a little confused why my version didn't work, as I thought I was relating the inner and outer queries with "clients.clientId = appointments.clientId"  Also, as a side note for anyone else, I had to change "clients.studentEmail" to "c.studentEmail" in order for the above example to work.

Comment: @hims056: In the original query, `client` referred to the `client` in the `not exists` query.  I removed the `join` in the `not exists` query.

Comment: Ah, okay I think I understand what was happening.  Thank you so much for helping with this query.  As a beginner, this technique will come in very handy.

Comment: @radleybobins: you might want to take a look at the explanation in my answer. Be aware that a `NOT EXISTS` can be expensive (in terms of performance) on large sets, because MySQL basically runs that subquery for every row in the outer query. An anti-join pattern is usually more efficient.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what resultset you are trying to return. But including the clients table in the subquery doesn't look right.

What we usually want is a correlated subquery. For example:

```
SELECT c.studentEmail 
  FROM `clients` c
  JOIN `invoices` i
    ON i.clientId = c.clientId
 WHERE i.datePosted > '2013-04-01' 
   AND NOT EXISTS 
       ( SELECT 1
           FROM appointments a
          WHERE a.clientId = c.clientId 
            AND a.serviceDirection = "Delivery" 
            AND a.date > '2013-07-01'
       )
```

Note that the `NOT EXISTS` subquery references `c.clientId`, which is the value from the `clientId` column of the `clients` table in the outer query.

We call this a "correlated subquery", because for each row returned by the outer query, we are (effectively) running the subquery, and using the `clientId` from that row in the predicate (WHERE clause) of the subquery.

The NOT EXISTS returns either a TRUE (if NO matching row is found) or FALSE (if at least one matching row IS found).

In terms of performance, this type of query can be expensive for large sets, because MySQL is effectively running a separate subquery for each row returned in the outer query. An anti-join pattern is usually (not always) more efficient (with suitable indexes available).

Another way to obtain an equivalent result, using the anti-join pattern:

```
SELECT c.studentEmail 
  FROM `clients` c
  JOIN `invoices` i
    ON i.clientId = c.clientId
  LEFT
  JOIN appointments a
    ON a.clientId = c.clientId 
   AND a.serviceDirection = "Delivery" 
   AND a.date > '2013-07-01'.
 WHERE i.datePosted > '2013-04-01' 
   AND a.clientId IS NULL
```

We use a LEFT JOIN to the appointments table, to find matching rows. Note that all of the predicates to find matching rows need to be in the ON clause (rather than the WHERE clause).

That returns matching rows, as well as rows that don't have a matching row in `appointments`.

The "trick" now is to include a predicate in the WHERE clause, that checks for a.clientID IS NULL.  That will exclude all the rows that had at least one matching appointment, so we are left with rows that don't have a match.  We can reference any column in appointments that is guranteed to be NOT NULL.  (We usually have an `id` column that is PRIMARY KEY (and therefore NOT NULL.)  But we can also use the `clientID` column, in this case, because every matching row is guaranteed to be not null, because it had to be equal to the clientId from the clients table, and a NULL value is never "equal" to any other value. (It's the equality condition in the JOIN predicate that guarantees us (in the query) that a.clientId is not null.

This pattern is called an "anti-join".

Answer (score 0):

In addition to knowing the right answer, it's equally beneficial to understand what was wrong

```
NOT EXISTS 
  (SELECT * 
  FROM appointments, clients
  WHERE clients.clientId = appointments.clientId 
  AND appointments.serviceDirection = "Delivery" 
  AND appointments.date > '2013-07-01')
```

basically mean "*There is no Delivery appointment dated after '2013-07-01' for ALL clients*". The reason why this "ALL" word appears here is because "client" in your sub-query has no relation to the outer-query's client, and thus is treated as a full table (i.e. ALL clients)

Answer (score 0):

I think a more efficient approach would be to use joins instead of subquery/Exists clause:

```
SELECT c.studentEmail 
  FROM `clients` c
    JOIN (select clientId from `invoices` i where i.datePosted > '2013-04-01') iclients
            ON c.clientId = iclients.clientId
    JOIN (select clientId from `appointments` a where a.serviceDirection = "Delivery" AND a.date > '2013-07-01') aclients
        ON c.clientId = aclients.clientId
```